# Package javax.enterprise.context missing in glassfish 4.1

Tags: cdi, glassfish-4

In the new Glassfish 4.1 the package javax.enterprise.context containing annotation SessionScoped for instance is missing.

Comment: Open `$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/modules/cdi-api.jar' you'll see the package is here. Could you give more detail on your problem?

Comment: When deploying my JSF application to Glassfish 4.0 @SessionScoped is pretty dereferenced - when deploying to Glassfish 4.1 it's not. I'm using Netbeans 8.0.1. When opening myProject>Libraries>Glassfish I cannot see the named package.

Comment: The package is definitly there. I guess the main problem is that you don't use Maven?

Comment: Sorry, but until now Glassfish was usable out of the box. I'm not familiar with configuring Glassfish and I'm trying to avoid learning it ...

Answer (score 10):

add cdi-api.jar to the project by right-clicking on Libraries, selecting Add JAR/Folder, and selecting cdi-api.jar from the modules folder of glassfish installation.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000827/523758 and the comment below, it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Hmmm ... cdi-api.jar is not in Glassfish 4.0 but in Glassfish 4.1 ... but it compiles with 4.0 and not with 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

is easy, right-click on project and click in **properties**, then in **Libraries** + Add Jar/Folder, in x:\Program Files\glassfish..