# javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, cdi, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

Dev env : Netbeans 8.0.2, JAVA EE 7, GlassFish 4.1
Creating a simple java class bean

```
    package com.introjsf;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author xiarnousx
 */
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerCDI {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Inject
    private AddressCDI address;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

The output

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped is not an annotation type
    at com.introjsf.CustomerCDI.<clinit>(CustomerCDI.java:17)
```

I did what this stackoverflow answer suggests [the package javax.enterprise.context is missing after glassfish update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076613/the-package-javax-enterprise-context-is-missing-after-glassfish-update)
 Yet no luck! any suggestion would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: This answer might help you : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964497/package-does-not-exist-after-upgrading-to-netbeans-8-0-1-and-glassfish-4-1/26000827#26000827](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964497/package-does-not-exist-after-upgrading-to-netbeans-8-0-1-and-glassfish-4-1/26000827#26000827)